# app appearance changes in different devices

Tags: android, android-xml

I created an app and when I give it to different friends with different devices they start to experiencing errors. For example, one of them is that in my device (Samsung galaxy S2) It looks like this:

[image]

And in another mobile (in this case samsung galaxy S3) like this:

[image]

This is the xml code that I use:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" 
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_nuevo_ver2" >
    </ImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rect_rojo">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/shopping_cart"
                    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp" />






                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtShopingCart"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="My shopping cart"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
                    </TextView>

                 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/recuadro_blanco">

                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtShopingCart"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
                    </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/linea_gris"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"></ImageView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llPhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="340dp"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/camara"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/camara" />




             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/txtShopingCart"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                 android:text="Click in the image to take a photo" >

                    </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageLinea"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/linea_gris"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"></ImageView>

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/llTab"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:weightSum="90">






             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/llTab1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical" >

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageMonkey"
                 android:paddingTop="5dp"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="40dp"
                 android:src="@drawable/do_the_monkey" >
            </ImageView>



             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/txtMonkey"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="  Do the Monkey  " >

    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                         android:id="@+id/imageLineaVertical"
                         android:layout_width="2dp"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:src="@drawable/linea_gris_vertical" >
            </ImageView>




           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/llTab2"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="39.79"
               android:orientation="vertical" >

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageCart"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:paddingTop="5dp"
                 android:layout_height="40dp"
                 android:src="@drawable/add_to_cart" >
    </ImageView>



             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/txtCart"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="    Add to cart" >

    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

           <ImageView
                         android:id="@+id/imageLineaVertical"
                         android:layout_width="2dp"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:src="@drawable/linea_gris_vertical" >
            </ImageView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTab3"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40.42"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageShare"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:paddingTop="5dp"
                 android:layout_height="40dp"
                 android:src="@drawable/share" >
    </ImageView>



             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/txtShare"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="    Share" >

    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I do to make it looks the same in all devices?

Comment: This is a broad filed. Have a a look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Answer (score 2):

I would stick your 3 bottom buttons to the bottom of the screen, and then let whatever that white space is expand down to take up the rest of the space. Try not to deal in absolutes when designing an android interface.

I would take a look at this, it will definitely help: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

One step would be to remove the absolute height-definition for `llPhoto` and instead rely on relative automatic positioning. If you need to have one item have a specific height, embed it in another layout that centers it automatically or provides scrolling (in case of devices that do not provide enough space to display the item).